# jQuery Isotope doesn't display strong, em tags correctly when inside other content - Is there a fix?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-isotope

Came across jQuery Isotope plugin and have been playing a bit with it.

One thing that I can't seem to get around is how to display text with markups inside (such us `<b>`, `<strong>`, `<em>`, etc) inside and isotope element

Code like the one below, when put inside an element causes some visual problems

```
<h3 class="cont-tlt">This is an article<em> italic </em>title</h3>
<p class="cont-txt">This is some <strong>important</strong> text for our viewers</p>
```

Check in fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/fGBxC/5/

Answer (score 0):

It does work, see [this fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/2U4dj/). Hope that helps...